# How to enable Java checkstyle for JavaDocs at Class level comments?

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

I am trying to enable JavaDocs at class level. Currently I only see http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod but nothing at class level

Comment: Check if you have included \**java\** in checkstyle config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [JavadocType](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks/javadoc/javadoctype.html) check. It will do what you're asking for both classes and interfaces.

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. Please update it with the correct link 

https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks/javadoc/javadoctype.html

Thanks!